# Invalid scopes Facebook API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have a business facebook App that has just been running fine when we add testers in user roles. I submitted a review and now no one is able to access the permissions anymore.

I get invalid scopes for:

- instagram_content_publish
- instagram_manage_insights
- instagram_basic

The steps I have taken are the following:

- submitted a review (that's currently pending)
- verified myself as an individual (not as a business)

I am not sure what happened - Any ideas?